# Find 5 closest points for all points in a MySQL table (Geo Spatial query)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, geospatial

I have a MySQL database table with 50,000 records, and I need to find the 5 closest points to each point to display on a website. Unfortunately, the query is computationally expensive, and takes a long time to query pretty much static information (the list of points will very rarely change)

I'm ultimately looking for a solution to crunch the entire table and set a new column with a list of the closest record IDs using something like `GROUP_CONCAT` to make a nice comma separated list

I can do one line at a time (Just using selects right now – updating rows after this is sorted)

```
SELECT c.ID, GROUP_CONCAT(items.ID) as list FROM cities as c, (SELECT ID FROM cities ORDER BY ST_Distance_Sphere(cord, POINT(-81.9242,32.5521), 3440) asc LIMIT 5) as items WHERE c.ID = 5185
```

`cord` is the lat/lng coordinate stored in the database as a geo-spacial POINT, The second `ST_Distance_Sphere()` Property is what is stored for the item ID 5185

Basically, I need to figure out how to either pass values into the nested `SELECT` query or there's a magic `JOIN` I'm not figuring out

Comment: Do you need to return 5 closest points to each of your 500k points (500k output rows)? Or you need in 5 points closest to one definite point (to a point either stored in the table or defined by its coordinates)?

Comment: 5 points for each of the 50K points, returning 1 point for each is easy enough it's making it multiple is where I'm struggling.

Comment: If this common task and it is spent time-critical then you may use pre-calculation. I.e. foк each point you calculate its 5 closest points into separate (overdefined) table, and query this table when you need this data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a magic JOIN in MySQL that would do it (PostgreSQL does have something close to such magic). What you can do lacking such magic is to use regular spatial join on distance condition.

The trick is that MySQL like many DBMS has [spatial index support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html) and reasonably fast spatial join when you use index and limit search using a distance condition. So if you query only points within a small distance - the query is much faster. The trick is how to figure out the appropriate distance? One way is to start with small search radius, then increase search radius for points where you did not find 5 points close enough.

I did couple posts about doing it in BigQuery, you can adapt the solution for MySQL and 5 nearest points rather than 1.

- https://mentin.medium.com/nearest-neighbor-in-bigquery-gis-7d50ebd5d63
- https://mentin.medium.com/nearest-neighbor-using-bq-scripting-373241f5b2f5